# Does Apache Kafka let consumers to check topic's data and get them if the condition was satisfied

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming

Suppose I have *n* producer that send data for every timestamp *t* to Kafka. The consumer's condition for getting data for timestamp *t*, is that data for timestamp *t* are received from all producer.

Does Kafka let consumer do such a check? Or have Kafka any strategy for such problem?

Comment: This is not supported. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610592/kafka-streams-filtering-broker-or-consumer-side and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376905/implement-filering-for-kafka-messages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implement filering for kafka messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376905/implement-filering-for-kafka-messages)

Comment: Does the consumer know the value of n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do filtering at Kafka broker itself, and consumer drivers also don't do any filtering. The Kafka wire protocol describes the fetch request here:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-FetchRequest

Basically, each fetch request will contain a set of topic, partition,offset and there is no content based filtering. Kafka is a message queue, and it on its own doesn't peek into the messages. Whatever filtering you need, should be in the processing logic. If some message doesn't match the filtering criteria, just skip it (off course offset has to be committed either automatically or by explicit call for all the messages)